# What is workaround for 'Type not compatible with table constraint' ssl error in Erlang R14B04?

Tags: erlang, version, erlang-otp

This is the web service request I make:

```
Erlang R14B04 (erts-5.8.5) [smp:4:4] [rq:4] [async-threads:0]

Eshell V5.8.5  (abort with ^G)
1> application:start(asn1).
ok
2> 
2> application:start(inets).
ok
3> 
3> application:start(crypto).
ok
4> 
4> application:start(public_key).
ok
5> 
5> application:start(ssl).
ok
6> 
6> 
6> 
6> Method = post,
6> 
6> URL = "https://testprosis.belbim.com.tr:1479/HostSwitchTxnService/SearchCardWithAuthP1",
6> 
6> Header = [],
6> 
6> Type = "application/json",
6> 
6> Body = "{ \"clientData\": { \"clientKey\": \"hts_sube1_client2\", \"clientPass\": \"n85uedpbsWJUZsuFnFFrVaEn\", \"clientConnectionIndex\": \"1100\" }, \"uid\": \"04362FBAA53080\", \"txnType\": \"5\", \"voidTransactionId\": \"0\", \"amount\": \"0\" }",
6> 
6> HTTPOptions = [],
6> 
6> Options = [],
6> 
6> R = httpc:request(Method, {URL, Header, Type, Body}, HTTPOptions, Options),
6> 
6> {ok, {{"HTTP/1.1",ReturnCode, State}, Head, ResponseBody}} = R.
```

This works in `Erlang 18`, I get the answer from the web request. But I run my server on `Erlang R14B04`. Here's what I get when I try to post data to web service:

```
{{badmatch,
        {error,
            {asn1,
                {'Type not compatible with table constraint',
```

I've read a lot about this error and I came to conclusion that this is the bug of `Erlang R14B04`. Everyone is advising to update `Erlang` but update is not solution for me because of some reasons.

Is there any workaround?